# Is it possible to assign footprints to components in LTspice?

Tags: ltspice, footprint

In Multisim, I can draw a circuit, assign footprints to the circuit components and export the file to Protel-format such that I can design component placement in another program (VeeCAD).

[image]

The exported file looks like this when opened in notepad.

```
[
R1
AX3_1
1k


]
[
C1
BOX2_1
1uF


]
(
1
R1-2
)
(
2
R1-1
C1-1
)
(
0
C1-2
)
```

I want to do the same thing in LTspice, however, it doesn't seem possible to assign footprints to components in LTspice. Here is the same circuit and the exported Tango-format file (LTspice cannot export as Protel but that is okay).

[image]

**Question**: Can I assign footprints to LTspice components?

Comment: It looks like the Tango export from LTspice uses the symbol name (e.g. it says "res" because the symbol is `res.asy`).  If you CTRL+rightclick the resistor and open the symbol and then do a "Save As" to another name (i.e. your desired package name) then you can build the circuit with those symbols and the Tango export should include the desired names.  Does that make sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the Tango export from LTspice uses the symbol name (e.g. it says "res" because the symbol is `res.asy`). If you CTRL+rightclick the resistor and open the symbol and then do a "Save As" to another name (i.e. your desired package name) then you can build the circuit with those symbols and the Tango export should include the desired names.

[image]

---

For example, if you saved a copy of `res.asy` as `AX3_1.asy` and then also `cap.asy` as `BOX2_1.asy`...then the Tango output of your same LTspice circuit built with those "new" symbols would look like this:

[image]

Looks like it turns the package names to all lowercase too, so hopefully that doesn't affect you.